# Outlook AddIn Zoom.Percentage

Tags: c#, vba, outlook, zooming, outlook-addin

Im trying to translate this VBA code from an Outlook AddIn to C#

```
Private Sub objInspector_Activate() Handles objInspector.Activate
        Dim wdDoc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document = objInspector.WordEditor
        wdDoc.Windows(1).Panes(1).View.Zoom.Percentage = lngZoom
End Sub
```

But I can't get access to the Panes.View.Zoom.Percentage property

The main idea is that when the user opens an email, he will get a custom zoom level.

What I got at the moment is:

```
void Inspector_Activate()          
 {             
// this bool is true
// bool iswordMail = objInspector.IsWordMail();

//I get the word document

Document word = objInspector.WordEditor as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document;

word.Application.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.Zoom.Percentage = 150;
// at this point i'm getting an exception
// I've also tried with 
// word.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Zoom.Percentage = 150; getting the same exception                      
}
```

The exception is :

> An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'
>   occurred in OutlookAddInTest.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: This object model command is not available in
>   e-mail.

I'm quite new in C# and Office addins, any advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Eugene Astafiev for his help.
The square brackets did the trick

VBA

```
Private Sub objInspector_Activate() Handles objInspector.Activate
        Dim wdDoc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document = objInspector.WordEditor
        wdDoc.Windows(1).Panes(1).View.Zoom.Percentage = 150
End Sub
```

C#

```
private void Inspector_Activate()
        {
            Document wdDoc = objInspector.WordEditor;
            wdDoc.Windows[1].Panes[1].View.Zoom.Percentage = 150;  
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `word.Windows.Item(1).View.Zoom.Percentage = 150` (where `word` comes from `Inspector.WordEditor`)

Comment: Nice try, thanks, but It doesn't work.  'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Windows' does not contain a definition for 'Item'

Comment: It looks like the sample code is in VBA. In C# the Item method is replaced with the indexer property. Try to use the following code instead: `word.Windows[1].View.Zoom.Percentage = 150;`

Comment: That did the trick!! so easy, `word.Windows[1].Panes[1].View.Zoom.Percentage = 150;`, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

> word.Application.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.Zoom.Percentage = 150;

What property exactly fires the exception?

Anyway, there is no need to call the Application and ActiveDocument properties in the code. The WordEditor property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class (not Word Application instance).

Comment: ActiveWindow fires the exception. I've tried with word.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Zoom.Percentage = 150; with the same result. Here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Zoom.aspx I have found  the zoom interface but I'm still not able to get the ActiveWindow.

Comment: Try to use the Windows property of the Word Application class to get an instance of the Window class.

Answer (score 0):

I've been wanting this forever, and then I stumbled on a nice project in the MSDN Gallery [Outlook 2010: Developing an Inspector Wrapper](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/outlook-2010-developing-an-c4470591). It has a set of wrappers for all the Outlook objects, so you get a true event for every item of interest. Not sure if it's the most efficient thing ever, but it seems to work.

I have trouble with my eyesight so want black everything, and zoom everything. I seem to be able to do that by overriding the Activate() method. It's all pretty new so we'll see if it survives long term.

```
    protected virtual void Activate() {
        var activeDocument = Inspector.WordEditor as Document;
        if (activeDocument == null)
            return;

        var mailZoom = GetSetting("MailZoom", 125);
        if (mailZoom != 0)
            activeDocument.Windows[1].View.Zoom.Percentage = mailZoom;

        if (GetSetting("MailBlack", true)) {
            activeDocument.Background.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 0;
            activeDocument.Background.Fill.Visible = msoTrue;
            activeDocument.Saved = true;
        }
    }
```

In this example, GetSetting is just a function that returns a setting from an INI file. you can use constants or some other storage method.

There might be a better way to get the white on black text, but this seems pretty good.